# Как сделать выпадающий текст C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, разметка

Нужно реализовать выпадающий текст, чтобы он не скрывал следующие элементы под собой, а двигал их ниже (как на скринах). Подскажите, как сделать максимально просто ?

[image: До]

[image: После]

Comment: Взяли `ItemsControl`, привязали его к коллекции, изменили вид на `Expander`, готово. Элементарное ведь задание)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TreeViewItem` используйте этот элемент
[вот ссылка для примера](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.13.php)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]